# spring jpa create double parenthesis query

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with JPA (EclipseLink) and Oracle 11. 
I have `CrudRepository` interface:

```java
public interface TransportDefRepository extends CrudRepository<TransportDef, Long> {
    public List<TransportDef> findByNameInOrderByNameAsc(List<String> names);
}
```

Calling `findByNameInOrderByNameAsc`  method creates query:

```sql
SELECT ID, NAME,
FROM TRANSPORT_DEFS WHERE (NAME IN (('A','B'))) ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

and Oracle throws exception:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Why there are double parenthesis in generated query?

Comment: Well, you might check your dialect is set to at least `Oracle10gDialect`, but there seems to be a lot of reports about this bug.

Comment: Could you provide the real query that's generated?

Comment: There's really a comma after NAME?

Comment: @Nicholas does ECLIPSELINK have a "dialect" ? Perhaps you mean Hibernate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
@Query("select t from TransportDef t where t.name in ?1 order by t.name asc")
public List<TransportDef> findByNameInOrderByNameAsc(List<String> names);
```

With @Query annotation eclipselink creates query:

```
SELECT ... FROM TRANSPORT_DEFS WHERE (NAME IN (?,?,?)) ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

It's only workaround - I have no idea why Spring Data JPA generates invalid query without this annotation...

Answer (score -2):

I am not so sure about that specially the need for you to pass a list in to be queried from your table but if I were you I would code it differently.

1.Instead of passing a list as an argument I would pass parameters. and do the
List names iteration on the service layer and still return list         from your repo. so my code on my repo would be like below

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM TRANSPORT_DEFS t WHERE t.name = :name)
List<TransportDef> findByNameInOrderByNameAsc(@Param("name") String name);
```

This would work you just need to tweak your logic on your service.

Comment: There's no need of writting the query yourself. Spring Data JPA should generate it for you..

Comment: So you'd execute  a potentiality large number of  queries rather than 1?

Comment: @AlanHay why would I want to send a list to my DB. while I can handle that logic on my service based on a specific criteria

Comment: @Rudy I don't want to create more than one query. I have posted my solution - query annotation with IN operator. It's only workaround but it's working now...