# EclipseLink query method generating extra nested parenthesis -- ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple Spring JPA query method on my users table, to return several users at once by PK:

```
List<AppUser> findByUserIdIn(Collection<Long> userIds);
```

When I call that with a collection of 2 longs, I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

The query EclipseLink generated is:

```
SELECT 
    USER_ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS, EXEMPT, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USER_ACTIVE 
FROM 
    APP_USER 
WHERE 
    (USER_ID IN ((?, ?)))
```

When I copy that into SQL Developer and put in the two long values for the parameters, I get the same error. If I remove the extra set of parenthesis around the values, like so:

```
    (USER_ID IN (?, ?))
```

The query runs fine.

**Questions:**

1. Why does Oracle care about the extra nesting? Shouldn't it be the same logical query?
2. More importantly, how can I get Spring/EclipseLink to stop producing it?

Comment: I found a similar question, but there weren't any real answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921151/spring-jpa-create-double-parenthesis-query

Comment: To me, that's a bug in Oracle's query parser imo.

Comment: for 1 ((x,y)) is a list of tuples or other lists, and every different from (x,y).  For 2 the issue is in how spring builds the query.  You can workaround the issue by creating the JPA query yourself and not wrapping the JPQL parameter in parenthesis.  "select a from AppUser a where a.id in :parameter".

Comment: Ahhhh. Yeah, the tuples explanation makes a lot of sense.